# How can I test an HTTP request from a model spec in Rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, carrierwave

I am uploading an image to my Imagecollection model in using CarrierWave, and would like to test that when I upload the image, it is actually available online.  And that when I delete the image, it is actually removed.

I'm using an S3 backend, so i'd like to test this in the model itself, without having to have any controller dependencies, or run integration tests.  So I would need to construct the url, Issue an HTTP reequest, and tests its return code.  This code doesn't work, but is there a way to do something similar to the following:

```
describe "once uploaded" do
  subject {Factory :company_with_images} 

  it "should be accessible from a URL" do
    image_url = subject.images.first.image.url
    get image_url                                   # Doesn't work
    response.should be_success                      # Doesn't work
  end
end
```

**EDIT:**

I ended up adding this to my Gemfile

```
gem rest-client
```

And using the :fog backend for my tests.   Ideally, I could change the backend during the test with something like

```
before do
  CarrierWave.configure do |config|
     config.storage = :fog
  end
end

describe tests
end

after do
  CarrierWave.configure do |config|
     config.storage = :end
  end
end
```

But that doesn't seem to actually do anything.

```
describe "once uploaded" do
  describe "using the :fog backend" do
    subject {Factory :company_with_images} 

    # This test only passes beecause the S3 host is specified in the url.
    # When using CarrierWave :file storage, the host isn't specified and it
    # fails
    it "should be accessible from a URL" do
      image_url = subject.images.first.image.url
      response = RestClient.get image_url
      response.code.should eq(200)
    end
  end

  describe "using the :file backend" do
    subject {Factory :company_with_images} 

    # This test fails because the host isn't specified in the url
    it "should be accessible from a URL" do
      image_url = subject.images.first.image.url
      response = RestClient.get image_url
      response.code.should eq(200)
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up redefining the spec as follows

```
  describe "using the :fog backend" do
    subject {Factory :company_with_images} 

    it "should be accessible from a URL" do
      image_url = subject.images.first.image.url
      rest_response(image_url).code.should eq(200)
    end
  end
```

with this helper

```
def rest_response url
  # https://github.com/archiloque/rest-client
  RestClient.get(url){|response, request, result| response }
end
```

and using the restclient gem

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with CarrierWave, you should be testing your code, not any external libraries or services it depends on. In other words, you want to test your class, not S3. I suggest mocking the calls to S3 made by your model to verify that it makes all the correct ones.

Comment: That's great in theory and all..    but there's no point in having tested code, if it doesn't work with the library or system you're using

Comment: Yes, but that would be a job for integration tests, not unit tests. Inside a unit test you want to verify that your code is sending all the right calls. Actually checking S3 is something best done either in a manual test, or something like a Cucumber feature, where you test the whole stack rather than just the one library.

Answer (score 0):

You can't test s3, unless the files are actually uploaded to s3. And in carrierwave, by default, it wont upload to s3.

instead, test that image_url is proper:

```
image_url = subject.images.first.image.url
image_url.should == "http://.....'
```

Comment: thanks, but yes.. that's the whole idea.   Think of it as a full integration tests of just the model layer

Comment: You're not getting the answers you want because you're trying to do stuff that people aren't doing.  You need your tests to be fast, isolated, and repeatable -- testing S3 and Google's services in your tests breaks that, and that's why it's frowned upon.

Comment: Ok fair point..  I guess my misunderstanding then, is why people aren't doing it.  I totally understand the need for fast tests, but at the end of the day, I need a working application, not passing tests.  So when I run my test suite, if something fails because of S3 or Google's service, I need to know about it - not be misled into thinking that everything is fine because the tests are green